# Formatar a visualização (PHP, MySQL e HTML)

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, pdo

Eu estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação, e eu preciso formatar a visualização na tela para o usuário. pois os campos data, valor e status, estão sendo representados da maneira que o MySQL armazena os valores, e o ano está aparecendo no padrão AAAA/MM/DD, o valor eu quero que apareça em R$ e o campo status que ta sendo representado por 1 quero que apareça APROVADO e o número 2 REPROVADO. Já fiz a parte dos SELECTS dentro do HTML utilizando PHP com acesso ao PDO.

```
<div class="container">
        <table class="table table-dark">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">ID</th>
                    <th scope="col">Nome</th>
                    <th scope="col">Título</th>
                    <th scope="col">Categoria</th>
                    <th scope="col">Data</th>
                    <th scope="col">Valor</th>
                    <th scope="col">Descrição</th>
                    <th scope="col">Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <?php
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM campos WHERE status_ped = 1 OR status_ped = 2";
                $busca = $conexao->query($sql);
                
                while ($array = $busca->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    $id = $array['id'];
                    $nome = $array['nome'];
                    $titulo = $array['titulo'];
                    $tipo = $array['tipo'];
                    $data_despesa = $array['data_despesa'];
                    $valor = $array['valor'];
                    $descricao = $array['descricao'];
                    $staus_ped = $array['status_ped'];?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $id?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $nome?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $titulo?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $tipo?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $data_despesa?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $valor?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $descricao?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $staus_ped?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </table>
    </div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: <td><?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($data_despesa));?></td> se quiser troca - por /

Comment: <td><?php echo ('R$ '. $valor.',00')?></td>

Comment: <td><?php echo ($staus_ped == 1 ? "APROVADO" : "REPROVADO");?></td>

Comment: https://ideone.com/O0CZcx